# How to write your own properties onto react-router's RouteHandler within typescript

Tags: typescript, reactjs, react-router

I am using TS nightly, to be able to use the JSX bits. I am also using react-router typings via definitelytyped (`tsd install react-router`).

The following is the render of the main route handler:

```
render() {
  var name = this.context.router.getCurrentPath();
  return (
    <div>
      <RouteHandler key={name} hub={this.props.hub} state={this.state}  />
    </div>);
}
```

This code part has a number of issues:

- context has been specified as `{}` without any chance to modify it. *I can fiddle around that one.*
- The properties I pass onto the RouteHandler are not specified on the corresponding type...

> error TS2339: Property 'key' does not exist on type 'RouteHandlerProp'.
>   ...

but from my understanding properties passed this way will be passed to the React Component to be rendered by the handler.

Does anybody know what I can do to get this to compile in typescript?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> context has been specified as {} without any chance to be modify it

Use a fat arrow `()=>`. More : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tvocUcbCupA

> The properties I pass onto the RouteHandler are not specified on the corresponding type

TypeScript interfaces are open ended. Add stuff to the `RouteHandler` interface in a `vendor.d.ts`:

https://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped/blob/5109e1269d6ab8e8e73b1a5e85d8ceb836d3099f/react-router/react-router.d.ts#L133-L146